# Custom $type value for serialized objects

Tags: c#, json.net

We're using Web API with Json.Net using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` in our serializer settings.  This works fine, but we use the type information only client-side, never for deserialization.  Our serialized objects look like this:

```
{
    "$type": "PROJECTNAME.Api.Models.Directory.DtoName, PROJECTNAME.Api",
    "id": 67,
    "offices": [{
        "$type": "PROJECTNAME.Api.Models.Directory.AnotherDtoName, PROJECTNAME.Api",
        "officeName": "FOO"
    }]
},
```

I would like to customize the value in the `$type` property so it reads as:

```
{
    "$type": "Models.Directory.DtoName",
    "id": 67,
    "offices": [{
        "$type": "Models.Directory.AnotherDtoName",
        "officeName": "FOO"
    }]
},
```

I already have a contract resolver that inherits from `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.  I figure what I need to do is turn off `TypeNameHandling` and add a custom property myself.  I'm 95% there:

```
protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var assemblyName = type.Assembly.GetName().Name;
    var typeName = type.FullName.Substring(assemblyName.Length + 1);

    var typeProperty = new JsonProperty()
    {
        PropertyName = "$type",
        PropertyType = typeof(string),
        Readable = true,
        Writable = true,
        ValueProvider = null // ????? typeName
    };

    var retval = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    retval.Add(typeProperty);
    return retval;
}
```

At this point I'm stuck with supplying the property's value.

I'm unsure that this is the correct approach because each of the `ValueProvider` types from Json.Net take a `MemberInfo` as a constructor parameter.  I don't *have* a `MemberInfo` to supply as a parameter, so.... I'm stuck.

How do I add a custom `$type` value?   Since I'm not doing deserialization in C# I will never need to convert the type information back into a type.

Comment: Don't add a `$type` property.  Instead create a [custom `ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) such as the ones in [JSON.Net: deserializing polymorphic types without specifying the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13598969/3744182), [Using a custom type discriminator to tell JSON.net which type of a class hierarchy to deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11099466/3744182) and [Newtonsoft.json serializing and deserializing base/inheirited where classes are from shared projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45923177/3744182).

Comment: I'm not doing deserialization in C#.

Comment: [`ISerializationBinder.BindToName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder_BindToName.htm) is called during serialization of polymorphic types to specify the type information to emit for `$type`, and so should do what you want.

Comment: Ahhhhh.  I was about to ask if I misunderstood the purpose of `ISerializationBinder`.  I'll check that out.

Comment: Note that the docs are a little obsolete because recently Newtonsoft had to replace use of [`SerializationBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffas09b2) which is apparently missing in some versions of .Net core with its own [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm).  If you are using Json.NET 10.0 or later, use ` 
ISerializationBinder`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than adding a synthetic `$type` property, you should create a [custom `ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) and override [`ISerializationBinder.BindToName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder_BindToName.htm).  This method is called during serialization to specify the type information to emit when [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) is enabled.

For instance, the following strips the assembly information as well as the `PROJECTNAME.Api.` portion of the namespace:

```
public class MySerializationBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    const string namespaceToRemove = "PROJECTNAME.Api.";

    readonly ISerializationBinder binder;

    public MySerializationBinder() : this(new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder()) { }

    public MySerializationBinder(ISerializationBinder binder)
    {
        if (binder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.binder = binder;
    }

    #region ISerializationBinder Members

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        binder.BindToName(serializedType, out assemblyName, out typeName);
        if (typeName != null && typeName.StartsWith(namespaceToRemove))
            typeName = typeName.Substring(namespaceToRemove.Length);

        assemblyName = null;
    }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can serialize your `DtoName` object with it as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    SerializationBinder = new MySerializationBinder(),
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- Newtonsoft introduced [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm) in [release 10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1) as a replacement to [`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.aspx), apparently because that type is missing in some versions of .Net core.  If you are using a version of Json.NET that precedes 10.0.1 you will need to create a custom version of that instead.

  Note also that [`SerializationBinder.BindToName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.bindtoname(v=vs.110).aspx) was introduced in .Net 4.0, so if you are using an old version of Json.NET and an old version of .Net itself then this solution will not work.
- As you are not doing deserialization in c# I simply threw an exception from [`BindToType()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder_BindToType.htm).  But if someone were to implement `BindToType()`, they should take heed of the caution from *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954)* and be sure to sanitize the incoming types to prevent construction of harmful types.

Comment: A wonderful answer, thank you sir/ma'am for your time and effort.