# Deserializing a a dynamic type with custom object creation with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

So let's say I have a:

```
List<IInterface> list;
```

that has been serialized with `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, so it has "dynamic" type information. I can deserialize it fine as **Newtonsoft.Json** can recognize the type from the `$type` and Json can use the correct constructor. So far so good.

Now say I want to override the creation converter with a mehtod:

```
CustomCreationConverter<IInterface>
```

that overrides the creation of the object:

```
public override IInterface Create(Type objectType)
```

At this point `objectType` will always be `IInterface` and not a derived implementation, so I have no way to create the correct object. The meta-information of `$type` is now lost.

Is there an elegant way to fix this?

Here would be an attempt that does not work:

```
public class CustomConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Example.IInterface> {
    public override Example.IInterface Create(Type objectType) {
        return Example.MakeObject(objectType); // this won't work, objectType will always be IInterface
    }
}

public class Example {
    public interface IInterface { };
    public class A : IInterface { public int content; };
    public class B : IInterface { public float data; };
    public static IInterface MakeObject(Type t) {
        if (t == typeof(IInterface)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return t == typeof(A) ? new A() : new B();
    }

    public static void Serialize() {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };

        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
        // serializer.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter()); // ?? can't have both, either CustomConverter or $type
        List<IInterface> list = new() { MakeObject(typeof(A)), MakeObject(typeof(B)) };

        using (StreamWriter sw = new("example.json")) {
            serializer.Serialize(sw, list);
        }

        // Now read back example.json into a List<IInterface> using MakeObject

        // Using CustomConverter won't work
        using (JsonTextReader rd = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader("example.json"))) {
            List<IInterface> list2 = serializer.Deserialize<List<IInterface>>(rd);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?

Comment: By design, a custom creation converter is going to work at cross-purposes to `TypeNameHandling.Auto`.  The former is responsible for manual construction, the latter tells Json.NET how to construct things automatically.  Can you share exactly how you want to combine these two functionalities?  If you're looking to inject some custom logic for parsing the `$type` value, the intended method is via a [Custom SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm).  See e.g. [Custom $type value for serialized objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49283251).

Comment: Say I still want to make use of the type information, but instead I have my own factory that given the Type returns an appropriate object of that Type (for which I cannot use the constructor).

`
class A : IInterface {}; class B : IInterface{};
IInterface MakeObject(Type t) { [code] }
List<IInterface> list = new List{MakeObject(typeof(A)), MakeObject(typeof(B))}
[serialize list with type info]
`

Comment: In that case I'd probably go for a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) and inject the factory method as [`JsonContract.DefaultCreator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreator.htm).  That way your factory code won't interfere with `TypeNameHandling.Auto`.  Does that work for you?  If so, I could add an answer if you [edit] your question to include a basic [mcve].

Comment: @FilippoL " I want to override the creation converter"  why do you want ? what is the problem? What are you trying to get in the end?

Comment: I can't use the constructor for the types, still I wan't to create them approrpiately using the saved type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you provide a custom converter such as [`CustomCreationConverter<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/customcreationconverter.htm) for a type, the converter is responsible for *all* the deserialization logic including logic for type selection logic that would normally be implemented by `TypeNameHandling`.  If you only want to inject a custom factory creation method and leave all the rest of the deserialization logic unchanged, you could create your own [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) and inject the factory method as [`JsonContract.DefaultCreator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreator.htm).

To implement this, first define the following factory interface and contract resolver:

```
public interface IObjectFactory<out T>
{
    bool CanCreate(Type type);
    T Create(Type type);
}

public class ObjectFactoryContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly IObjectFactory<object> factory;
    public ObjectFactoryContractResolver(IObjectFactory<object> factory) => this.factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        if (factory.CanCreate(objectType))
        {
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => factory.Create(objectType);
            contract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = false;
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Next, refactor your `IInterface` class hierarchy to make use of an `IObjectFactory` as an object creation factory:

```
public class InterfaceFactory : IObjectFactory<IInterface>
{
    public InterfaceFactory(string runtimeId) => this.RuntimeId = runtimeId; // Some value to inject into the constructor
    string RuntimeId { get; }
    
    public bool CanCreate(Type type) => !type.IsAbstract && typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    public IInterface Create(Type type) => type switch
        {
            var t when t == typeof(A) => new A(RuntimeId),
            var t when t == typeof(B) => new B(RuntimeId),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException(type.ToString()),
        };
}

public interface IInterface
{
    public string RuntimeId { get; }
}

public class A : IInterface
{
    [JsonIgnore] public string RuntimeId { get; }
    internal A(string id) => this.RuntimeId = id;
    public int content { get; set; }
}

public class B : IInterface
{
    [JsonIgnore] public string RuntimeId { get; }
    internal B(string id) => this.RuntimeId = id;
    public float data { get; set; }
}
```

(Here `RuntimeId` is some value that needs to be injected during object creation.)

Now you will be able to construct your list as follows:

```
var valueToInject = "some value to inject";
var factory = new InterfaceFactory(valueToInject);
List<IInterface> list = new()  { factory.Create(typeof(A)), factory.Create(typeof(B)) };
```

And serialize and deserialize as follows:

```
var resolver = new ObjectFactoryContractResolver(factory)
{
    // Set any necessary properties e.g.
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
};
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = resolver,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var list2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IInterface>>(json, settings);
```

Notes:

- Newtosoft [recommends](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver) that you cache and reuse your contract resolvers for best performance.
- Newtonsoft also [recommends](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) that

  > [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameHandling.htm) should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializationBinder.htm) when deserializing with a value other than None.

  For why, see e.g. [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182) or [External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055/3744182).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eo8OG0).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. Seems to be working also in my "real-life" scenario.