# Deserialize JSON string to object which has abstract types

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a complex nested json to my object.
The only thing is that in my object I use abstract types, so it must have some logic to use the correct derived class.

The types are saved in enums.

To explain it I will keep it fairly simple and do we only nest once, but for my purpose it is more nested with objects and types.

##### The json

```json
{
   "screen":{
      "type":"Component",
      "footer":{
         "type":"Bar"
      },
      "header":{
         "type":"Top"
      }
   }
}
```

##### The classes

```
public abstract class Screen
{
    public abstract ScreenType Type { get; }
}

public enum ScreenType
{
    Component,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e
}

public sealed class ComponentScreen : Screen
{
    public override ScreenType Type => ScreenType.Component;
    public Header? Header { get; init; }
    public Footer? Footer { get; init; }
    public bool? ShowStuff {get; init; }

}

public abstract class Header : ITyped<HeaderType>
{
    public abstract HeaderType Type { get; }
}

public enum HeaderType
{
    Top,
    b,
    c,
    d
}

public sealed class TopScreenHeader : Header
{
    public override HeaderType Type => HeaderType.Top;
    public string MyStuff { get; }
}
```

It isn't possible to just change all the abstract types, or writing converters, since there are multiple abstract types with times X derived objects.
The JSON is also not consistent.

##### My current code using newtonsoft

```
var screen = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Screen>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()

}
```

Which doesn't work and gives errors:

```
Could not create an instance of type Screens.Screen. Type is an interace or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'screen', line 1, position 10.
```

Comment: Consider checking the steps described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995865/deserializing-json-to-abstract-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON to abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995865/deserializing-json-to-abstract-class)

Comment: No since this doesn't work when each derived object has derived objects it is nested multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Deserializing with TypeNameHandling is **only** possible if the $type property is set that maps to the exact object it should deserialize to.
Without a $type property it does not deserialize with typenamehandling to my nested abstract objects.

The $type is set when serializing the json with newtonsoft and TypeNameHandling as setting. So the received JSON should be deserialized correctly.

If this isn't possible, than there are 2 "solutions":

- Writing code that adds the correct $types to the json
- Writing converters

For me writing code inplace of converters was easier and faster.
I am using it for a prototype, but I **wouldn't** recommend it for production.

Both are errorprone to changes made in the package.
And therefore aren't a solid solution, but it is the solution for the specific constraints and goal.

#### This is how it should look like with $types:

```json
{
   "$type": "MyPackage.Screens.Screen, MyPackage"
   "screen":{
      "$type": "MyPackage.Screens.ComponentScreen, MyPackage",
      "type":"Component",
      "footer":{
         "$type": "MyPackage.Footer.BarFooter, MyPackage",
         "type":"Bar"
      },
      "header":{
         "$type": "MyPackage.Header.TopHeader, MyPackage",
         "type":"Top"
      }
   }
}
```

In my case the "type" property is not necessary for deserializing and can be removed.

#### Deserializing in code

To deserialize in code you need to use a wrapper where the screen is defined.
Because deserializing directly to screen (abstract) is not possible.

#### note

The $type should be above the type property otherwise it isn't handled correctly. I don't know why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but if you are considering migrating to .NET 7+ and `System.Text.Json`you can use `System.Text.Json`'s ability to handle [type hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#polymorphic-type-discriminators):

```
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "type")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ComponentScreen),"Component")]
// all other Screen types ...
public abstract class Screen
{
    public abstract ScreenType Type { get; }
}

[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "type")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(TopScreenHeader), "Top")]
// all other Header types ...
public abstract class Header : ITyped<HeaderType>
{
    public abstract HeaderType Type { get; }
}
```

Note that your json does not represent screen but some screen holder type so:

```
class ScreenHolder
{
    public Screen Screen { get; set; }
}
```

And usage (for `footer` I have used simple class):

```
var js = """
{
   "screen":{
      "type":"Component",
      "footer":{
         "type":"Bar"
      },
      "header":{
         "type":"Top"
      }
   }
}
""";

var deserialize = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ScreenHolder>(js, new JsonSerializerOptions{PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});
```

As for Newtonsoft Json.NET there are following options:

- Follow the [custom converter approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579193/2501279)
- Change "type" to "$type" (since this property name seems to be [hardcoded in the sources](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/55a7204f9b9546aa07145591d42046d509176ad4/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L53)) and then create custom [`SerializationBinder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287052/2501279).

Also note that using `TypeNameHandling` with other option other than `None` and without proper `SerializationBinder` [can lead to application vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/2501279).

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug in you json convert code , you need add a root class. Also you need to include a class name in your json string to point what class to use to deserialize. To do it easier to create a base class for all your abstract classes

```
public class Root
{
    public ComponentScreen Screen { get; set; }
}
public class DataBase
{
    public string ClassName { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
}
public abstract class Footer : DataBase
{
    public abstract HeaderType Type { get; }
}

public abstract class Header : DataBase
{
    public abstract HeaderType Type { get; }
}

public sealed class ComponentScreen : Screen
{
    public override ScreenType Type => ScreenType.Component;
    [JsonConverter(typeof( AbstractToConcretConverter))]
    public Header? Header { get; init; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof( AbstractToConcretConverter))]
    public Footer? Footer { get; init; }
    public bool? ShowStuff { get; init; }

}
```

it will create a json string of this kind

```
{
   "screen":{
      "type":"Component",
      "footer":{
         "type":"Bar",
     "ClassName":"ScreenFooter"
      },
      "header":{
         "type":"Top",
      "ClassName":"TopScreenHeader"
      }
   }
}
```

you can use this converter to convert from base class to concrete one

```
public class AbstractToConcretConverter : JsonConverter<DataBase>
{
    public override DataBase ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DataBase existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        return (DataBase)jObj.ToObject(Type.GetType((string)jObj["ClassName"]));
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DataBase value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```